# Mapbox: createState function for MapWidget returned an old or invalid state instance

Tags: ios, flutter, mapbox

I'm fairly new to Flutter and MapBox thus sorry if this question is too naive

I am creating an app where there is a page that looks like this:

```
Column
- Expanded
-- ListView
--- MapBox Map Widget
--- Many Rows
```

When I scroll down till the Map disappears, and then when I scroll back, I get this error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building _SelectionKeepAlive(state: _SelectionKeepAliveState#b960e):
The createState function for MapWidget returned an old or invalid state instance: MapWidget, which is not null, violating the contract for createState.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart':
Failed assertion: line 5573 pos 7: 'state._widget == null'
```

I know this might be caused by the ListView destroying and recreating the map view, but how to solve this error ?

Another solution that I am thinking about but haven't tried yet is to use a Scroll View instead of List View because a Scroll View seems to do not destroy the map view when it's hidden.

Is there a solution without resorting to a ScrollView ?

Here is the part of code in my build function where the map is created:

```
newTripPlanListView.insert(0,Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0), child: 
        ConstrainedBox(constraints: new BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 500), child: MapWidget(
          key: ValueKey("TravelMap"),
          onMapCreated: (map) {
            log("Map is created");
            travelMap = map;
            
          travelMap!.annotations.createPointAnnotationManager().then((pointAnnotationManager) async {
              // some code to set up annotations and move the camera
            });
          },
      ),),));
```